# Advice on loading and persisting images

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data, uiimageview

So I'm building one of my first swift apps and I'm currently in the phase of building a friends list. I've built the backend API which returns JSON with a name and an avatar URL. I'm using the hyper sync (https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync) library to sync the data from my API to `CoreData`. works great:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJaXm.png

As you can see in the second image I'm loading an avatar image. My question is about how to deal with the storage and fetching of the avatar images.
I wrote my own code on top of `Alamofire` to loop the friends on the complete request and fire of an async request to fetch the images and write the returned image as `NSData` into `CoreData`.

Then when you view your friend I pull the `NSData` into an `UIImageView` and it shows the image.
However I've also seen libraries like this one https://github.com/hirohisa/ImageLoaderSwift that seem to be called whenever you load the `UIImageView`.

What is the best way to deal with showing image and persisting this data?

Comment: Generally, I would include the URL in your image, and then asynchronously download images using a library like SDWebImage. (ImageLoaderSwift might be fine; I haven't used it.) Unless you have aggressive caching needs for your app, I wouldn't use any of the disk caching stuff, I'd just rely on the Foundation URL Cache.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was thinking along the lines of WhatsApp for example, it also always shows the avatars of the users I have in my chats list. Maybe I should cache a small thumb version of the image and load the larger ones one the fly. So, in general, is it ok to store NSData objects in CoreData? Any pros/cons?

Comment: It is ok to save NSData objects in CoreData. Saving (avatar) images in CoreData typically slows it down. Likely you will change to store the images on disk sooner or later.